# Access JS Enum Value in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, enums

I'm making a form that uses the  tag.  I have an enum which I'll call `myEnum` for now, with values `Val1`, `Val2`, and `Val3`.  I want to assign options in the select tag values from the enum as such:

```
<select>
    <option value=myEnum.Val1>Text Goes Here</option>
```

What is the proper syntax for doing this?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have "enums."

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to print out your HTML in a Javascript block, something like this:

```
document.write('<select><option value="' + myEnum.Val1 + '">Text</option>...');
```

Another option would be to use jQuery/Javascript to assign the values during runtime.

```
<select><option id="option1">Text</option>...
```

And the following in a `$(document).ready` block:

```
$("#option1").attr("value", myEnum.Val1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JS variables directly in HTML like that, you have to populate the select via javascript.

```
var myEnum = ["January","February","March"];
var select = document.querySelector('select');

function createOption(optionValue, index) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = index;
  option.innerHTML = optionValue;
  select.appendChild(option);
}

myEnum.map(createOption);
```

you can check a more complete example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/nicokant/pen/gWEyOv)